# Where is the code that the output <html lang="en"> determines in Magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2.2, html, seo

Can someone indicate me where I can find the code that the lang attribute for the html tag determines?
I'd like to make the lang attribute to show `<html lang="en-US">` instead of `<html lang="en">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Source code you are looking for is located in **vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml**.

To change this behavior copy the above file to your current theme directory.

For Example:-
app/design/frontend/YOURVENDORNAME/YOURTHEME/Magento_Theme/templates/root.phtml

Around line 11 Change the below line

```
<html <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $htmlAttributes ?>>
```

To

```
<html <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ "lang=en-US"; ?>>
```

Comment: Thanks for reacting. Given the fact that i have different store views, i’d like to have it by means of php variables instead of a harcoded value

Comment: Yes it is possible to have it in php variable,  you can add a condition to check the current store view by either store id or storename. Base on the store you can set the value in a php variable.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is no need to overwrite the root template file.

1. Just listen to "layout_generate_blocks_after" event

> ```
> <event name="layout_generate_blocks_after">
>     <observer name="sgecom_seo_html_lang" instance="SgEcom\Seo\Observer\Frontend\HtmlLang" />
> </event>
> ```

2. In your observer :

> ```
> use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
> use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
> use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config as PageConfig;
>
> class HtmlLang implements ObserverInterface
> {
>     protected $pageConfig;
>
>     public function __construct
>     (
>         PageConfig $pageConfig
>     )
>     {
>         $this->pageConfig = $pageConfig;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * @inheritDoc
>      */
>     public function execute(Observer $observer)
>     {
>         $this->pageConfig->setElementAttribute
>         (
>             PageConfig::ELEMENT_TYPE_HTML,
>             PageConfig::HTML_ATTRIBUTE_LANG,
>             'TEST' //Put here the value you want
>         );
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. This is the correct way to modify the HTML Language Code. The 2 other answers are not best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can either check with store name or store id and assign the lang attribute

```
<?php 
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeID       = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId(); 
$storeName     = $storeManager->getStore()->getName();

$lang = "lang=en-US"; //Default value for lang attribute
if($storeID==1)
{
 $lang = "lang=en-US";
}
else if($storeID==2) {
 $lang = "lang=en-GB";
}
?>

<html <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $lang ?>>
```